# Material UI: "styled" child component not applying css rules

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm having an issue where I'm using the styled function to style a custom React component but the styles are not being applied. In the example below, I would expect the `Child` component to have the `color: red` style, but it doesn't. The `sibling` component, however, is styled correctly.

```js
import "./styles.css";
import { Child } from "./Child";
import { Typography } from "@mui/material";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";

const StyledChild = styled(Child)(() => ({
  color: "red"
}));

const StyledSibling = styled(Typography)(() => ({
  color: "blue"
}));

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <StyledChild />
      <StyledSibling>Sibling</StyledSibling>
    </>
  );
}
```

```js
import { Typography } from "@mui/material";
import { FunctionComponent } from "react";

export const Child: FunctionComponent = () => {
  return <Typography>Child</Typography>;
};
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/serverless-river-uzoyhc?file=/src/App.tsx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`styled` causes a `className` prop to be passed to the wrapped component, but `Child` isn't passing the `className` prop along to `Typography`.

Here's an example of how to fix `Child.tsx`:

```
import { Typography } from "@mui/material";
import { FunctionComponent } from "react";

export const Child: FunctionComponent<{ className?: string }> = ({
  className
}) => {
  return <Typography className={className}>Child</Typography>;
};
```

[image: Edit elastic-mayer-yr131s]